# R : define a function within a function

Tags: r, function, nested, function-declaration

(about R language)

I was trying to declare/define a function, within another function. 
It doesn't seem to work. I don't think this is exactly a bug, it's probably expected behavior, but I would like to understand why ! Any answer linking to relevant manual pages is also very welcome.

Thanks

Code :

```
fun1 <- function(){
  print("hello")
  fun2 <- function(){ #will hopefully define fun2 when fun1 is called
    print(" world")
  }
}

fun1() #so I expected fun2 to be defined after running this line
fun2() #aaand... turns out it isn't
```

Execution :

```
> fun1 <- function(){
+   print("hello")
+   fun2 <- function(){ #will hopefully define fun2 when fun1 is called
+     print(" world")
+   }
+ }
> 
> fun1() #so I expected fun2 to be defined after running this line
[1] "hello"
> fun2() #aaand... turns out it isn't
Error : could not find function "fun2"
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this as opposed to defining a single function which has a dependency (i.e. calls) another function?

Comment: it is normal behaviour. `fun2` is defined in the environment of `fun1` while `fun1` is defined in the global environment. That is why you cannot call directly `fun2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work as you expect but is generally considered bad practice in R:

```
fun1 <- function(){
  print("hello")
  fun2 <<- function(){ #will hopefully define fun2 when fun1 is called
    print(" world")
  }
}
```

where I changed `<-` to `<<-` in line 3 of the function definition. Execution:

```
> fun1 <- function(){
+     print("hello")
+     fun2 <<- function(){ #will hopefully define fun2 when fun1 is called
+         print(" world")
+     }
+ }
> 
> fun1()
[1] "hello"
> fun2()
[1] " world"
```

Comment: Thanks. I failed to consider variable scopes.

Comment: This behavior is really going to confuse other users of this function (provided there are other users of this function) and - as mts started off the answer with - is considered bad practice.  The answer from Data Munger is far more R-like and used in many packages.

Comment: Ok thanks for the insight. I'll upvote other DataMunger's answer but will stick to this as "selected answer" because my mistake really was about variable scopes though.

Answer (score 6):

another way if for 'fun1' to return a function that you assign to 'fun2':

```
> fun1 <- function(){
+   print("hello")
+   # return a function
+   function(){ # function to be returned
+     print(" world")
+   }
+ }
> fun2 <- fun1()  # assign returned function to 'fun2'
[1] "hello"
> fun2()
[1] " world"
```